# Windows 7: how can I add an IP range in the "route" command?

Tags: windows, command-line, routing

I'm using two network connections, and I tried using the "route" command so that when I access a specific internal IP on my LAN, it would use connection 1, anything else would go normally through connection 2 (which doesn't have access to my LAN).

The problem is I have a bunch of internal IP's that I need to access, and the "route" command doesn't seem to allow me to add an IP range instead of specific IP. And connection 1 doesn't have internet access, so I can't use it as my default connection.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Your help is appreciated

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The route command is all about routing ranges of IP.  The key to doing ranges is using the [netmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netmask) portion of the route command.

### Basic IP networking lesson

An IPv4 address is a 32 bit number that represents an address on the internet.  Taken in binary, the IP address `10.0.0.1` would look like this:

```
10      .0       .0      .1
00001010 00000000 0000000 00000001
```

The netmask specifies which portion of the address is the fixed part of the range by specifying a binary 1, and the variable portion of the range is a 0.  So, a netmask of `255.255.255.255` represents all bits are fixed and therefore will only route the give IP.  A netmask of `0.0.0.0` means all bits are variable, or in other words this matches every IP address.  `0.0.0.0` is used for the default route.  So, if you want to specify a range, you just need to specify the bits in the netmask you want to match.

If you wanted a route to apply to all the addresses from `10.0.0.0` to `10.0.0.255` your route command would look like

```
          Dest Ip       Netmask       Gateway
route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1
```

If you wanted a route to apply to only `10.0.0.100` and `10.0.0.103` your command would look like

```
route ADD 10.0.0.100 MASK 255.255.255.252 10.0.0.1
```

And if you wanted a route to apply to all addresses `10.0.0.0` to `10.255.255.255` your route would look like

```
route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1
```

You can also specify in the `route` command the interface it should use using the `IF` parameter:

```
route ADD 10.0.0.0 MASK 255.0.0.0 10.0.0.1 IF 2
```

Comment: Man this was EXTREMELY helpful. Thank you very very much! :D

Comment: this is easily the best description of netmask i've ever seen!

Answer (score -1):

As you are using Windows 7, execute `cmd.exe` as an administrator by going to the *Start Menu*, typing `cmd.exe` in the search box, right clicking on `cmd.exe`, and selecting *Run as administrator* (or pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

You will see a difference from the normal Command Prompt. Within this elevated Command Prompt you can add your static route, i.e.

```
route add 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 192.168.0.1 -p
```

Comment: This question was about routing multiple IPs, not about how to run the `route` command.