# Custom route table for a specific application?

Tags: windows-7, routing

I'm on a network with two internet connections.
One is a WAN access to a corporate network (with custom firewall rules), the second is a direct internet connection.

By default, all communications are directed to the wan connexion (default route to the wan router). I can set up routes to the direct internet connexion, based on a classic target network/ip/mask to a specific router.

Is it possible to have a custom route for a specific application, and not a specific IP adress ?
In fact, I don't know what are the outbound IP addresses used by the APP, and I have to make it use directly the internet connection. The application unfortunately does not support proxy server (and the protocol is proprietary).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers.

I finally used microsoft network monitor to find the target ip addresses, then I manually set up routes for theses targets.
There is near 45 target ip addresses ! :(

Comment: It's probably too late for you now - but if others read this. You can set up ranges with the Route command. This often works well for your scenario as the private IP's will likely be on a small set of subnets. See here for a good example: http://superuser.com/questions/121998/windows-7-how-can-i-add-an-ip-range-in-the-route-command

Comment: Thanks @lex, but this is only valid for consecutive ip adresses. In my cases, there was a lot of "random" ip adresses, hard to join in ranges. But thanks anymore for the link. It's still valuable for a wider audience.

Comment: Definitely cases where it isn't a help and a shame yours was one of them. I would just clarify; it isn't just valid for consecutive addresses (as you could have non-consecutive masks) but if your IP's are too widely dispersed or you need fine grained IP address filtering (not subnet wide) then it won't help much. Hope it helps in future!

Answer (score 2):

[ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) - a utility that intercepts an application's internal winsock calls.  The website doesn't claim Win7 support, but it appeared to work on my test system (`netstat` showed my chosen app was indeed bound to the alternate local IP address I provided).  This is 32-bit only, and if your app doesn't use standard windows sockets calls, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about a virtual machine?  Create a second OS instance with [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/) (there's a free edition) or [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) and you can route the virtual network adapter it uses straight to your direct internet connection.  Then for any app you want bypassing the WAN without individual routing, just run it on the virtual machine.  Maybe not the most elegant solution but if you only have a few apps where traditional ip/port routing wouldn't do, this might be the way to go.

If you're willing to spend a little VMWare Workstation has a feature called "Unity" which might make working between all your apps a little more seamless.  Also check into Microsoft Virtual PC.  If you're on Windows 7 Professional or higher, you might even be able to leverage [XP Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode) for this (assuming your application is backwards compatible).

Comment: the application rely on some hardware that is not compatible with vmware